# Grey Card color balancing in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to implement Grey Card color balancing of Adobe Lightroom using ImageMagick. I got some information from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15564&sid=f885b9f7f0fa604c94e78443e89628cf&start=30) to balance color using grey card:-

```
convert MAIN.JPG ^
( +clone ( REFERENCE.JPG -gravity Center -crop "128x128+0+0" -scale "1x1" -negate ) +dither -interpolate Integer -clut ) ^
-compose Overlay -composite ^
FIXED.JPG
```

I tried this one, but the result is different from Lightroom. Could anyone tell me why this is not accurate and how I can get the same result as in Lightroom?

Here are the images:-

**Original one:-**
[image]

**Balanced using Lightroom:-**
[image]

**Balanced using ImageMagick:-**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you could try another linear color space and other gray values until it matches. In Imagemagick, I changed the mid-gray value to .466 and tried both RGB and XYZ colorspaces.

```
infile="8Mvyi.jpg"
gray=0.466
declare `convert "$infile" -colorspace RGB -crop 90x40+106+208 +repage -format "rratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.r]\ngratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.g]\nbratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.b]\n" info:`
echo "$rratio $gratio $bratio"
convert "$infile" -colorspace RGB -color-matrix \
"$rratio 0 0 \
0 $gratio 0 \
0 0 $bratio" -colorspace sRGB result3a.png
```

[image]

```
infile="8Mvyi.jpg"
gray=0.466
declare `convert "$infile" -colorspace XYZ -crop 90x40+106+208 +repage -format "rratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.r]\ngratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.g]\nbratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.b]\n" info:`
echo "$rratio $gratio $bratio"
convert "$infile" -colorspace XYZ -color-matrix \
"$rratio 0 0 \
0 $gratio 0 \
0 0 $bratio" -colorspace sRGB result3b.png
```

[image]

Neither quite match your Lightroom image. So all I can suggest is play with those two colorspaces and adjust the mid-gray value until you get as close a match as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this question in detail on the Imagemagick Discourse server at http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32473#p148599. The solution is as follows using -color-matrix in RGB (rather than sRGB) mode.

```
infile="8Mvyi.jpg"
gray=0.5
declare `convert "$infile" -colorspace RGB -crop 90x40+106+208 +repage -format "rratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.r]\ngratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.g]\nbratio=%[fx:$gray/mean.b]\n" info:`
convert "$infile" -colorspace RGB -color-matrix \
"$rratio 0 0 \
0 $gratio 0 \
0 0 $bratio" -colorspace sRGB result3.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As per Imagemagick answer result2 is little bit darker then lightroom and result3 is little bit lighter but not accurate.

Comment: I do not know what Lightroom does. I matched result2 to convert the average gray shade measure by a large region of the gray card to 0.5 in linear RGB space. Perhaps changing that to 0.466 would help? result3 assumes that the matching is done in RGB colorspace. Perhaps Lightroom used some other linear colorspace like XYZ. As I mentioned in my other post, A mid-gray card should have sRGB of 46.6%. That is what I did in result1 (actually 50%). So Lightroom is not really properly matching to mid-gay or the result would have your gray card resulting with 46.6% gray, which is like my result1.

Comment: Correction. In result 2, I matched the color of the gray card in your Lightroom result to 0.5 is sRGB colorspace.